# How to run a command on a remote machine using perl?

Tags: perl

i have downloaded all the modules required for running below mentioned perl script:

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = "172.16.170.116";
my $user = "HGamit";
my $password = "";

#-- set up a new connection
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
#-- authenticate
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
#-- execute the command
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("perl C:/Monitor/ltp.pl C:/monitor");
```

But the error is: Can't connect to 172.16.170.116, port 22: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. at C:/Perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm line 206.
then i tried telnet but it is not working.

```
use warnings;
use Net::Telnet;

$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>2, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('172.16.170.116');
$telnet->waitfor('/HGamit\s*/');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/\s*/');
$telnet->print('Blue');

#$telnet->cmd('ver > C:\\log.txt');
$telnet->cmd('perl C:/Monitor/ltp.pl C:/monitor');
```

Can anyone provide some solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: Before scripting you should check that is in fact possible to connect using SSH or telnet. Check firewall and services on the target machine. Are you able to telnet to port 22? (using a standard telnet application)

Comment: looks like a firewall issue to me or the SSH daemon is not running at all on the remote machine...

Answer (score 0):

You can write the client server program using IO::Socket. You can also implement the encryption and user authentication. This model provides you control of sending command and return the data back to client when it completes the execution. You can limit the number of commands to be executed on server by modifying the inherited PATH variable in the server program for added security.
If you need help with the code. I can post my code for you.

Thank you,

Sukhbir Dhillon

Addteq

Comment: HEy Sukhbir, I want to open remote text,xml file using perl, and parse and update that file for update.

Comment: HEy Sukhbir, I want to open remote text,xml file using perl, and parse that file to update.</n>Example: Remote server Name: incdforty , IP : 172.16.23.110, Username:"myname" pwd: "psswrd".....The file location may vary. I wanted to compare and merge files on two different remote servers, like:- File 1 content -: key=abc2000,2003 and file 2 content-: key=2005, i just wanted to update first file with content of second file from my local machine to other two remote servers for which i have admin credentials... that will be really helpful , if you can give me snippet or guide for this task.